# C# adding click events to a list box

Tags: c#, listbox, onclick

I'm trying to add a click event to a list box but for some reason nothing happens when I click an item in my list box.

My guess and from what I've read, the code should look something like this

```
private void listBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Code Ex. TextBox1.Text = "Success";
    }
```

That's not working though. Anyone know how to get this to happen?  Wouldn't mind knowing the double click and other click variations too....

Comment: show your aspx markup please

Comment: Im codding on windows in Visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to trigger when you 'click an item' in the box, why don't you try SelectedIndexChanged instead?

Comment: I Would do it that way but I really want to use a double click. I just wanted to understand how to add a single click event first.

Comment: Selected index change dosn't function how I would like it to but its simpler than trying to get a click event on a listbox item.

Answer (score 2):

You coded the event handler but didn't add it to the click event... something like this:

```
listBox1.Click += new EventHandler( listBox1_Click );
```

Comment: This code would need to be called when your form is constructed.

Comment: If you're using asp.net its part of the lifecycle. Are you, or are you using Winforms?

Answer (score 1):

Webform?
if so, did you check 'autopostback' = true?

Example with selectindexchanged:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem>a</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>b</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>

protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

That will make a postback as soon as the user clicks on one item. 
I'm not sure there is a doubleclick for that kind of stuff.

Comment: huh? Thats is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Autopostback forces the post back if value changes. Sadly i m not sure it's gonna work with click, but it does with SelectedIndexChanged.

Comment: Thanks for the code but thats just to complicated for a novice like myself.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that the property "AutoPostBack" is enabled (="True")? :-) That happens often to me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the click events apply to the listbox items, probably just the parent box. I'd loop through the items and register the events. Or do it on databind.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft visual studio 2017
Get your main form ( with the list box ) into Form design view
Select your list box item which you have dragged onto the main form
Now your properties box for the list box has come live on the right hand side of the development window
Now look at the top of the properties box for the menu item with the 'jag of lightning' on it
Click on that...Voila your double click event is there

```
private void lbx _DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /*  Do good stuff here  */
}
```

Cheers me dears
Jim