# Create ListBox items from text file with 2 variables

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

So, I would like any help to populate a ListBox that is going to show a website name and if it's clicked go to a specific url.

This is what's inside of the text file:

```
#first website
http://firstwebsite.com

#second website
http://secondwebsite.com

#third website
http://thirdwebsite.com
```

I can read the file and populate the listbox with the name, but cannot put the url working.

```
FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder;
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");

StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

if (file != null)    {
    var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream.AsStream()))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();

                    if (line.StartsWith("#") {
                        listbox.items.Add(line);
                    }
```

Any help is great.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your text file reading and Listbox creation code

Comment: @Jonathan  Done ;-)

Comment: Do you have any control over the input text file? If possible, you should more strongly structure the text file, for example as json or xml, to be able to get the data out consistently. As it is, you are saying that lines starting with "#" are names, but are not using any token to distinguish urls. You could perhaps use 'http'

Answer (score 1):

If you want it in the "Click" event, I mean when you click on the Item, below code works.

```
  private void listBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = ((ListBox)(sender)).Text;
        Process.Start(str);
    }
```

Handle NULL conditions and exceptions.

Add System.Diagnostics namespace for "Process".

Answer (score 0):

I've created a very simple console to test this. 
Here is what I came up with

```
    var _listBox1 = new ListBox();

    //just adding a url for example
    _listBox1.Items.Add("http://www.google.com");

    //here I am just setting the selected value
    _listBox1.SetSelected(0, true);

    var selectedUrl = _listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

    //this will start off the default web browser
    Process.Start(selectedUrl);
```

So the `Process.Start()` can be put in any event handlers for that listbox. **I.E *SelectedIndexChanged* event**

```
    private void _listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object pSender, EventArgs pArgs)
    {
        var selectedUrl = _listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        Process.Start(selectedUrl);
    }
```

Comment: I think he asked for click event

Comment: @pavanChandaka i'm not sure if there is already a OnClick event for a listbox. but SelectedIndexChanged should do it. According to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646214/c-sharp-adding-click-events-to-a-list-box) SelectedIndexChanged is preferred. Maybe this [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197659.aspx) will help?..

Comment: I added click event in below answer

Comment: Thanks but what I want is to pick the text file info 2 by 2 line; first line is the item (#first website) that is going to populate the listbox and the second is the url on selectedItem.

Comment: @Rpgccv hmm it seems that you have a bigger problem that needs to be broken down into smaller tasks. It would be helpful to focus your question. Honestly, it is hard to imagine what you want to achieve. but  I'd probably create two listboxes. populate one with website, then the other with the url. Hope that helps